# Adding A Header when using Swagger UI

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui

The endpoint where my `swagger.json` file (`localhost:8000/rest/swagger.json`) requires an `AuthType` header to access it. How can I get Swagger UI to add this when it makes its initial request for the `swagger.json` file?

---

What I've tried so far:

```
$(function () {
    var token = 'xxx';
    window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        url: "http://" + location.host + "/rest/swagger.json",
        dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
        supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
        onComplete: function (swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {
            var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("AuthToken", token, "header");
            window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("AuthToken", apiKeyAuth);
            $('pre code').each(function (i, e) {
                hljs.highlightBlock(e)
            });
        },
        docExpansion: "none",
        apisSorter: "alpha",
        showRequestHeaders: false
    });

    swaggerUi.load();
});
```

But when I open Chrome Dev Tools and look at what request was made to `localhost:8000/rest/swagger.json` it has no `AuthType` header and has a `401 Unauthorized` response.

Note: It doesn't seem like the `onComplete` function ever gets called (i'm guessing it requests `swagger.json` before that would usually get called so it falls into the `onFailure` block instead when the request fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you have `window.swaggerUi`, but have not yet assigned the `swaggerApi` variable to the `window` object.

Try:

```
onComplete: function (swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {

    window.swaggerApi = swaggerApi;

    var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("AuthToken", token, "header");
    window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("AuthToken", apiKeyAuth);
    $('pre code').each(function (i, e) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(e)
    });
}
```

Second:

While the browser may be able to figure the correct `swaggerUi` variable try for the load:

`window.swaggerUi.load();`

Instead of:

`swaggerUi.load();`

Answer (score 3):

I will provide you my scenario. To be very honest the READ-ME of swagger is not upto the mark(that is my view) . They have not mentioned anything about adding a header to the url request.

My use case was that i had to call my API to get **JSON response**.(My API was protected by **login_required** decorator , which requires **xcsrf-token** to be sent in the header )

In your case, yours **localhost:8000/rest/swagger.json** is analogous to my API.

## *How to approach this problem?*

1. When we **SwaggerUIBundle**.A key named **"spec"** ( will explain **spec** later in the snippet) has to be mapped with **JSON response** value . This  **JSON response** provides initial structure for **swagger-ui** page .

### What are you saying ? What kind of UI are you talking about ? What is the structure of JSON Response ?

[Click here for Swagger-UI example](http://petstore.swagger.io/)

### To make page of this type using swagger-ui you need to supply it with JSON reponse

[Click here for JSON reponse that you need to generate either using APIs or in your case **ocalhost:8000/rest/swagger.json**](http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)

2. Use AJAX request to make a call to your API or 
   **localhost:8000/rest/swagger.json**.
3. Now in your success call, **JSON** has to be equated to **"spec"**.

## Explanation Using Code Snippets

1. Instantiate **SwaggerUIBundle object**. Notice **spec** key which has to be mapped to **JSON response** value. **dom_id** can be ID of any div.

```js
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    spec: {},// put JSON response here.
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      // yay ES6 modules ↘
      Array.isArray(SwaggerUIStandalonePreset) ? SwaggerUIStandalonePreset : SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.default
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
  window.ui = ui
```

2. Now enclose this object instantiation, in a function .

```js
window.foo = function(spec){
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    spec: spec,
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      // yay ES6 modules ↘
      Array.isArray(SwaggerUIStandalonePreset) ? SwaggerUIStandalonePreset : SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.default
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
  window.ui = ui
}
```

3. Let us see how we can use ajax calls to call this function. We can add any token during this AJAX call.

```js
window.onload = function() {
   function apiCall(uri, data, methodType) {
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  //Add header to the URL . 
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!this.crossDomain) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });
  
  $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    method: methodType,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      // Calling the function which instantiates swaggerbundle object
      foo(response)
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
  });
}


// You can write your own getCookie function . 
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
  
  //['GET','POST'] 
  apiCall('http://localhost:8000/rest/swagger.json',{},'GET');
  
}
```

4. Here is the final snippet .

```js
window.foo = function(spec){
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    spec: spec,
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      // yay ES6 modules ↘
      Array.isArray(SwaggerUIStandalonePreset) ? SwaggerUIStandalonePreset : SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.default
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
  window.ui = ui
}

window.onload = function() {
   function apiCall(uri, data, methodType) {
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  //Add header to the URL . 
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!this.crossDomain) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });
  
  $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    method: methodType,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      // Calling the function which instantiates swaggerbundle object
      foo(response)
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
  });
}


// You can write your own getCookie function . 
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
  
  //['GET','POST'] 
  apiCall('http://localhost:8000/rest/swagger.json',{},'GET');
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that your answer does not provide any new information to the problem - looks like you wanted to ask a new question instead. Please take your time and read through the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask